# Trying to install Nodejs version 18.0.0 or higher on alpine linux 3.14

Tags: node.js, linux, jenkins, groovy, apk

I have a jenkins job that is running alpine linux 3.14.
and
I am trying to install nodejs version 18.0.0 or higher on alpine linux v3.14.

Any suggestions on what I could try next

I have tried the following commands so far-

> apk add --update nodejs-current     (This installed the nodejs version 16.11.1.)

> apk add nodejs=18.9.0               (This gave an error "world breaks")

Answer (score 4):

You can try installing the nodejs package from edge repository as mentioned in [alpine package keeper documentation](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Package_Keeper#Add_a_Package).

However, you should be careful while using the edge packages in production, for the reasons mentioned in the [edge repository documentation](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge).

```bash
apk add nodejs --update-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main --allow-untrusted
```

You can check the nodejs version available in the edge from [Alpine Linux packages](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nodejs&branch=edge&repo=main&arch=&maintainer=).